# R - Multiply the entire column in R to a list, based on a factor column

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose we have the following data-set:

```
dat<-data.frame(num = 20:29, names = c(rep("Harry",2), rep("Gary",2), rep("Dairy",3), rep("Harry", 3)))

   num names
1   20 Harry
2   21 Harry
3   22  Gary
4   23  Gary
5   24 Dairy
6   25 Dairy
7   26 Dairy
8   27 Harry
9   28 Harry
10  29 Harry
```

And we also have the following values for each factor level:

```
fvals <- c(Harry = 1, Gary = 2, Dairy = 3)
```

The goal is to multiply the `num` level by these factors by the `fvals` according to the `names` level (matching it in the `fvals` variable). For example, the desired output for this set of data should be

```
20 # 20 * 1
21 # 21 * 1
44 # 22 * 2
46 # 23 * 2
72 # 24 * 3 
75 # 25 * 3
78 # 26 * 3
27 # 27 * 1
28 # 28 * 1
29 # 29 * 1
```

I have been doing this by converting the factor variable into a matrix with binary variables for each level, and then proceeding with matrix multiplication. But it was quite confusing trying to convert the matrices / vectors such that R can do multiplication on (and such that the level columns match). Also I'm not sure if the mat mul method will be efficient with a large number of observations. Just wondering if there's a better alternative to do this.

Comment: library(data.table); setDT(dat); dat[, num := num * .GRP, by = names ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea. Notice that I set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because it is easier to work with character vector directly.

```
dat<-data.frame(num = 20:29, 
                names = c(rep("Harry",2), rep("Gary",2), rep("Dairy",3), rep("Harry", 3)),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fvals <- c(Harry = 1, Gary = 2, Dairy = 3)

dat$num * fvals[dat$names]
# Harry Harry  Gary  Gary Dairy Dairy Dairy Harry Harry Harry 
#    20    21    44    46    72    75    78    27    28    29
```